# "Implicit Any? to Any cast" warning when passing Any? type variable in as Any? type parameter

Tags: swift

The warning `Expression implicitly coerced from 'Any?' to Any` is raised when passing an `Any?` type value in as an `Any?` type parameter but I don't see where casting is happening. It also seems to only happen with dictionary values. The example below shows when it happens:

```
func someFunc(_ aParam : Any?) {}

let testDict : Dictionary<String, Any?> = ["Test": "Hello"];
someFunc(testDict["Test"]);
```

If the function is called with a normal `Any?` value, there is no warning, like so:

```
let test : Any? = nil;
someFunc(test);
```

Comment: Basically optional dictionary values are nonsensical in Swift (and btw. forbidden in Objective-C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary look ups return optional values because the key might not exist.  In the case of a non-existent key, the look up returns `nil`, so the type of the dictionary look up has to be optional.

In your case, your values are of type `Any?`, so a look up from that dictionary returns a doubly wrapped optional `Any??`.  So you are trying to pass a value of type `Any??` to a function that takes `Any?`.

If you use *optional binding* to handle and unwrap the dictionary access, everything works:

```
let testDict : Dictionary<String, Any?> = ["Test": "Hello"];
if let value = testDict["Test"] {
    // "Test" key is valid
    someFunc(value);
}
```

Comment: Right so if I was to do `let test = someFunc(testDict["Test"]!)` that wouldn't error when "Test" is nil because all you've unwrapped is the dictionary finding the value? Is there anyway to take in a N level optional wrapped value so I can just pass in `testDict["Test"]` without crashing due to unwrapping if the value is nil or if the key doesn't exist?

Comment: I'd recommend just unwrapping the dictionary lookup. If you want to treat a non-existent key the same as looking up a value that has `nil`, then `testDict["Test"] ?? nil` works. At least now you understand why. If the value in the dictionary is nil, it returns it wrapped as `Optional(nil)` and the `??` unwraps that to regular `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Dictionary<String, Any>` instead of `Dictionary<String, Any?>` as the `Dictionary` Type.

```
    let testDict : Dictionary<String, Any> = ["Test": "Hello"];
    someFunc(testDict["Test"]);
```

Comment: I extrapolated the example from my real code where the value in the dictionary actually can be nil which means I can't use Dictionary<String, Any> as it causes a compile error

Comment: A dictionary cannot have a nil value corresponding to a key.

Comment: Optional values are nil and it can have an optional value though, like if I did <AnyHashable : Any?> I could then set a nil value like ["test": nil]